# Liferay - Adding Page

Tags: liferay, hide

I am using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

When You go to Add -> Page there is a popup list which show you type of new site and it is ugly.

Where I can hide it? I want to remain only accept button.

Edit: I want to hide only if it is really hard to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an [custom theme](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7) on your page and use CSS to hide it.

Comment: Yea, that's not a problem I think. I think I put this wrong. I want it to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up a few terms. I'm assuming that you mean the list of page templates, e.g. when you create a new top level page, you see the page templates "Blog", "Forum" or similar (I can barely remember them from 6.1 times). These are PageTemplates. You can remove all PageTemplates (implying that you won't be able to use them any more) and they won't be offered any more.

Other than that I agree with dube - IMHO it's enough to just hide it with CSS. Only the administrator, who is able to create a new top level page (and when they create a new top level page) will see them anyway. So it's not the regular usecase and just hiding them in CSS does not impose any security issue.